# to extract latest value from json output file which contains multiple values

Tags: json

I want to extract the latest sha value and the latest date from "author" section in the below json output
https://api.github.com/repos/jstedfast/MailKit/commits/master.

Is there anyway i can curl & grep the values or by any other means. I am looking for some options.

{
  "sha": "24234ad38234897278828a593ec2ee9dde0cbb5e",
  "node_id": "MDY6Q29tbWl0MTYwNjM3MzU5OjI0MjM0YWQzODIzNDg5NzI3ODgyOGE1OTNlYzJlZTlkZGUwY2JiNWU=",
  "commit": {
    "author": {
      "name": "Lazaro Clapp",
      "email": "lazaro@uber.com",
      "date": "2020-02-22T04:04:32Z"
    },

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: My preferred way would be writing a node script to do it in javascript. Or you could use jq if you prefer command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier to do in a more full featured scripting language:

- Python
- Javascript
- Ruby

Here's an example in python

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/jstedfast/MailKit/commits/master'
response = requests.get(url).json()

print(response.get('sha'))
print(response.get('commit', {}).get('author', {}).get('date', None))
```

Comment: It'd be worthwhile familiarising yourself with the ```.get()``` method used on python dictionaries.